# XQuery Remove Elements - Attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have an XML from end system which require to remove all empty elements or attributes that have `empty or null` value.

Example

```
<Element>
    <fn att=""></fn>
    <fn att="1"></fn>
    <fn></fn>
    <fn att="">
      <child>1</child>
    </fn>
</Element>
```

This is my script given using XQuery to check and remove them

```
declare function local:remove-empty-elements($nodes as node()*)  as node()* {
   for $node in $nodes
   return
     if ($node instance of element())
     then if (
       (normalize-space($node) = '') 
       and (not(normalize-space($node/@*)))   
     )
          then ()
          else element { node-name($node)
        }
       { $node/@*, local:remove-empty-elements($node/node())}
     else if ($node instance of document-node())
          then local:remove-empty-elements($node/node())
     else $node
};
```

This is successfully remove the elements and tag node that are single. But when i put multiple attributes in one element

*e.g.*
`<fn att1="Data" att2="1"></fn>`

The function itself fails.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thank you before.

** UPDATE **

As per har07 answer, if i want to change the function to remove the attribute that having empty value, is there any suggestions? I try with the logic if below but still sending the same result.

```
declare function local:remove-empty-elements($nodes as node()*)  as node()* {
   for $node in $nodes
   return
     if ($node instance of element())
     then if (
       (normalize-space($node) = '') 
       and (not($node/@*[normalize-space(.)]))    
     )
          then (
            /* updated code here */
            if(($node/@*[normalize-space(.)])= '')  then ()
            else
              $node/@*[normalize-space(.)]

          )
          else element { node-name($node)
        }
       { $node/@*, local:remove-empty-elements($node/node())}
     else if ($node instance of document-node())
          then local:remove-empty-elements($node/node())
     else $node
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part was causing the problem :

```
and (not(normalize-space($node/@*)))
```

Call `normalize-space()` function in predicate for *individual attribute* instead of passing all attributes to the function at once, like so :

```
and (not($node/@*[normalize-space(.)]))
```

**update :**

Regarding the question update, you can use the same predicate to filter the attributes so that you end up with non-empty attributes only. In the *inner `else`* block, set content of the returned element as follow :

```
else element {node-name($node)}
             { 
                $node/@*[normalize-space(.)], 
                local:remove-empty-elements($node/node())
             }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. If i want to remove the attributes if the value is empty, is there any suggestions? please see the update above.